# Proving quadrilateral angle is greater than another

Tags: geometry

How do you prove that one side of a quadrilateral is greater than another when you are given that two sides are equal and one angle is greater than another?

Given: quadrilateral $ABCD$, $AB=AD$, and $\angle B > \angle D$

Prove: $DC > BC$

Comment: I believe that the question is wrong. Take $B$ to be a point close to the origin above the x-axis, $A = (2,0), C=(3,0)$ and $D$ is a point close to $(4,0)$ below the x-axis, such that the conditions on the angles are satisfied. Then $DC$ is close to 1 and $BC$ is close to 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking into account the comment of @Calvin Lin I assume that the given quadrilateral is convex. (When the quadrilateral is concave at $C$ the statement is wrong.)

The triangle $ABD$ is isosceles with base $BD$. It follows that in triangle $BCD$ the angle at $B$ is larger than the angle at $D$; whence the side $CD$ is larger than the side $CB$.

Comment: This solution assumes that $ABCD$ is a convex quadrilateral. You need to use directed angles, in the event that the quadrilateral is concave at $C$. If so, then since $\angle ABC > \angle CDA$, hence $\angle CBD < \angle CDA$ (since $\angle ABD = \angle BDA$)

Answer (score 0):

Since $\angle B > \angle D$ thus $\cos \angle B < \cos \angle D$. Applying cosine rule, we get that

$$ \frac{AB^2+BC^2 - AC^2}{2 \times AB \times BC} = \cos \angle B < \cos \angle D = \frac{ AB^2 + DC^2 - AC^2} { 2\times AD \times DC} $$

Use the fact that $AB=AD$, cross multiplying and shift terms, we get that

$$(BC-DC)(AB^2 + DC\times BC - AC^2 ) > 0 $$

Hence, we have $BC < DC $ if and only if

$$ AB^2 + BC \times  DC < AC^2 $$

This clearly need not be true, like if we have $AB > AC$ already.

---

As an explicit counter example, take

$A = (0,0), B = (0,13), C = (4,0), D = (12, 5)$

It satisfies the conditions as:

$\cos \beta = \frac{13}{\sqrt{189}} \approx 0.945$ and $\cos \delta = \frac{169 + 89 - 16 } { 2 \times 13 \times \sqrt{89} } \approx 0.986 $ hence $\delta < \beta$

However, we have:

$BC = \sqrt{183} > DC = \sqrt{89} $.

As mentioned, it contradict's Christian's solution because $ABCD$ is not convex.

Comment: You have a wrong sign for $DC \cdot BC$, it should be $(AB^2 - DC \cdot BC - AC^2)$.

Comment: @njguliyev The signage looks right to me.